# Referenced Java package not copied to console application

Tags: java, netbeans

I am working on a java project using Netbeans7.4 after ages.

Here is structure of my prototype project. I have a Library project (B) that references MS SQL JDBC driver package (S). This project has a simple class that opens connection to SQL server and then closes it. I have a console application (A) that references library project B. Everything compiles fine.

When I instantiate class in project B to open connection, I get driver not found. After digging around I found that SQL driver jar file is not copied to my console application. Once I added that SQL driver package jar file as referenced library in console application as well, everything worked fine.

I come from Visual Studio background where all referenced library gets copied to consuming application. How do I accomplish same in Netbeans/Java world, if it is possible. For example if I add my library project (B) as reference to console application (A) then my SQL JDBC package reference in project B should be recognized as well.

Thanks

Comment: Use Maven, Ivy, or a similar dependency management/build tool.

Comment: I may use some build management tool some time in future. Currently I am just trying to learn my way back into java one step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike VS where the linker is complain all references inside the objects in the Java world the references is hidden and may spread along other jar libraries that is not linked into the whole application but needs to include them on `classpath` so the Java VM could load classes referenced by your application. netbeans IDE has the project properties where you could include project dependencies. You may also create a project libraries that combine a set of jars referenced by your application.

Comment: Can you elaborate some more on what you are suggesting? I think I am already doing what you are suggesting. In Netbeans, package dependencies get added under "Libraries" folder. If that is the case, then I already have my JDBC package referenced in library project. It is fine upto this point. By why should I have to add the same JDBC package dependency in my console application as well?

Comment: The console application might also has dependency to the JDBC if it used to connect to the DB. You may also add your library project as a dependency to the console app, so you will get transitive dependency to JDBC libraries.

Comment: Console application does not interact directly with JDBC. Only library project is used to connect to database and get resultset. I am encapsulating all DB related details in library project only.

Comment: the console app is the main project, and it should have all dependencies resolved, in contrast to library project.

Comment: do you understand what is a transitive dependency? netbeans should have the option to export transitive dependencies to your console project when you build it.

Comment: I finally found "Copy Dependent Libraries" option in project settings. But this only copies libraries in "lib" folder under "dist" folder of my library. But this option does not work for "transitive" dependency. It seems modifying build file is only way left to copy all dependencies.

Comment: yes, you should copy libraries or you include them on classpath the project should reference that library to make sure it's working and loading classes that require your application. This is always work "transitive" dependency is just a reference your project is done.